# Azure container permissions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Im reading this [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-9-shared-access-signatures/).

I have an azure container called "test" that is set to private in azure.
That container has a scorm package in it "121/HEEDENNL/story.html"

I'm using the code below to set the permissions of the folder to read.
However that story.html file needs several other files to run properly.
The story page opens and doesn't return a 403 or 404.
but the files it trying to reference to to make the page run properly are not loading.

How can I get all the files needed for story.html to run properly, be set to read access also?

I thought changing the containers permissions would allow that file to access the files needed.

What am I missing here?

```
    public ActionResult ViewContent(int id)
    {
        const string pageBlobName = "121/HEEDENNL/story.html";

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Common.Constants.Azure.ConnectionStringUrl;

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        //// Retrieve a reference to a container.
        // CloudBlobContainer learningModulContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(Common.Constants.Azure.LearningModulesContainerName);
        CloudBlobContainer learningModulContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");

        PrintBlobs(learningModulContainer);

        CloudBlockBlob myindexfile =  learningModulContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(pageBlobName);

        SharedAccessBlobPermissions permission = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.None;
        permission = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;


        var token = GetSasForBlob(myindexfile, permission,30);
        //this isn't finished.....must get learning module
        var module = DataAccessService.Get<LearningModule>(id);

        var url = $"{Common.Constants.Azure.StorageAccountUrl}{"test"}/{module.ScormPackage.Path.Replace("index_lms", "story")}{token}";

        return Redirect(token);
    }

 public static string GetSasForBlob(CloudBlockBlob blob, SharedAccessBlobPermissions permission, int sasMinutesValid)
    {
       // var sasToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        var sasToken = blob.Container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            Permissions = permission,
            SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15),
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(sasMinutesValid),
        });
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}", blob.Uri, sasToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get all the files needed for story.html to run properly, be set to read access also?

Firstly, if possible, you could put these css&js&image etc files that your html page reference in a [allow-public-access container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-manage-access-to-resources#grant-anonymous-users-permissions-to-containers-and-blobs).

Secondly, you could provide [URL with SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#what-is-a-shared-access-signature) of the blob resource, and add reference like this in your html page.

```
<link href="https://{storageaccount}.blob.core.windows.net/styles/Style1.css?st=2017-06-15T02%3A27%3A00Z&se=2017-06-30T02%3A27%3A00Z&sp=r&sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=%2FWwN0F4qyoIH97d7znRKo9lcp84S4oahU9RBwHTnlXk%3D" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Besides, if you’d like to host your web app, you could try to use [Azure app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/).

Comment: Hi @CsharpBeginner, any updates? Are you able to access blob resources as expected now?